# How can I make a non-member function which uses an overridden function?

Tags: c++, oop, operators

In this code I try to overload += operation basically. Everything looks okay in non-member parts but when i write a non-member function, (+ operation in this part) It gives **invalid abstract return type** error and says **+= operation is pure within vector1d**. How can I solve this problem?

```
class AbstractBase{
        public:
        virtual AbstractBase &operator+=(const AbstractBase &other)=0;

        private:
        }
     ////   
        class Vector1d:public AbstractBase{
        public:
        Vector1d &operator+=(const Vector1d &other);

        private:
          int size_;
          vector<double> data_;

        }
        //non member func
        Vector1d operator+(const Vector1d& vec1, const Vector1d& vec2);


        ///


        Vector1d &Vector1d::operator+=(const Vector1d &other){
                cout<<"sum operator is called"<<endl;
                for(int i = 0; i < other.size_ ; i++)
                data_.at(i) += other.data_.at(i);
                return *this;
            }

        Vector1d operator+(const Vector1d& vec1, const Vector1d& vec2){
        return  (Vector1d) vec1 += vec2;
        };
```

Comment: Can't operators be pure virtual?

Comment: The problem is that operator+=(AbstratctBase) and operator+=(Vector1d) have different signatures, so the latter does not override the first.

Comment: only return types of virtual functions are covariant but not argument types

Comment: I don't mean to start a flame war, but placing the `&` next to the function name as opposed to the type, is confusing.

Comment: There are many other errors with your code (e.g. missing `;` after class declarations, is `vector` `std::vector`? - if so no `#include` and no `using` statement). Please be sure to paste the example that you used when you got your exact error message.

Comment: @StoryTeller agree, but then say the same thing about positioning of `*` and people call you a mental defective

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the C++11 `override` contextual keyword when overriding.  That will move your error closer to where you made your mistake.  Which is that you did not override.

You are told this elsewhere, but it is confusing.

This:

```
virtual AbstractBase &operator+=(const AbstractBase &other)=0;
```

Has a different signature than this:

```
Vector1d &operator+=(const Vector1d &other);
```

And the second does not override the first.  It just overloads.  (They are different!)

You are violating the LSP in addition ([see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), which basically states your design has fundamental errors.  I lack information on how to fix that problem.  LSP violation does not cause build breaks.

To fix your build break, simply do:

```
Vector1d &operator+=(const AbstractBase &other) override; // and maybe final
```

*(The return types do not match exactly; this is ok, and the `override` keyword checks it, because of covariant return type rules in C++.  Covariance does not apply to `const&` arguments (aka, in) in any sensible language (contravariance could sensibly, but C++ does not supply that for free, and you are not trying to do that anyhow).)*

And for the body:

```
Vector1d &Vector1d::operator+=(const AbstractBase &other_abstract){
    auto& other = dynamic_cast<Vector1d const&>(other_abstract); // can throw
    std::cout<<"sum operator is called"<<std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < other.size_ ; i++)
      data_.at(i) += other.data_.at(i);
    return *this;
}
```

This now throws a bad cast if the abstract type does not match the type you expect.  Which is horrible, but it builds.

The LSP error is that your abstract base `+=` implies any two objects with the same abstract base can be `+=`'d.  Your implementation does not agree, quite sensibly.  This means your class heirarchy is junk and should be thrown out and possibly not replaced.  But that is a wider problem than I can cover in a SO answer about your technical build break.

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, you never override `operator+=(const AbstractBase &other)`.

You provide a new `operator+=` that takes a `const Vector1d&`, but this only allows using `+=` with the derived type.

The base class operator `+=` can be used with any `AbstractBase` so when you override this, you need to preserve the signature so that the derived implementation also works with any `AbstractBase`.

This may not makes sense for your class hierarcy, so think carefully about the utility of the abstract base class' `operator+=`.

Answer (score 3):

Even if `Vector1d` inherits from `AbstractBase`

`Vector1d &operator+=(const Vector1d &other);`

doesn't have the same signature as

`AbstractBase &operator+=(const AbstractBase &other)=0`

Consequently it cannot be a candidate for the override.